# unexpected output from shell script

Tags: shell-script, rhel

The following script expected to check if directory exists and size is more than 10000KB, archives and deletes files.

The output.log says that tracedir does not exists when script is run using crontab and getting error code 1, but actually it exists.

I have also tried to print the directory in for loop, tracedir value printed properly.

```
#!/bin/bash


sts=$(date)

echo "Script started running at $sts" > output.log

lsnrdir=$ORACLE_BASE/diag/tnslsnr/$HOSTNAME/listener/alert/

thr=10000

for i in $(ps aux | grep ora_smon | grep -v grep | awk '{print $11}' | cut -c10-17)

do

a=$(echo "$i" | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')

tracedir=$ORACLE_BASE/diag/rdbms/$a/$i/trace/

if [ -d $tracedir ]; then

size="$(du -s --exclude=*.tar.gz $tracedir | awk '{print $1}')"

if [ "$size" -ge $thr ]; then

echo "The trace and alert log size in $i  is: $size KB" >> output.log

echo "Trace and alert log archive started in $i ...." >> output.log

tar -czf $tracedir/dbtrace.tar.gz $tracedir

status=$?

if [ $status -ne 0 ]; then

echo "The error code is---"$status >> output.log

fi

echo "Trace and alert log archive completed in $i" >> output.log

sleep 5

tail -n 100 $tracedir/alert_$i.log > $tracedir/$i.log
mv $tracedir/$i.log $tracedir/alert_$i.log


find $tracedir -name "*.trc" -delete
find $tracedir -name "*.trm" -delete


echo "Removed trace files and log files in $i" >> output.log

else

echo "Trace log size in $i is not greater than $thr KB" >> output.log

fi

else

echo "No trace directory exists in $i" >> output.log

fi

done
```

Comment: Is `ORACLE_BASE` and `HOSTNAME` set in the cron job's environment?  I'd be slightly surprised if `ORACLE_BASE` is set.

Comment: ^^ this, and quote file names!

Comment: ORACLE_BASE and HOSTNAME are not set in cron job environment. If i run the script manually without cron, it works fine

Comment: I explicitly declared and set ORACLE_BASE and HOSTNAME in script and it is solved.